# How to traverse back through the tree after reaching to the end in DFS- Javascript

Tags: javascript

This may sound very naive, but I'm working my path through algos and need help in figuring out the traversal using DFS.

I'm getting the response from a fetch () and storing the data in an array. and using `Array.shift()` to get the first node from the array, pass it to the url as an id and call for another fetch() to get data related to that id.
By doing this I do reach the end of one side, however I dont know how should I go back to the root and check if there are any more children.

here is code:

```
     data={
            id: "647634",
            depth: 1,
            data: ["node1","node2","node3"]
        }
```

the data for every node call look like above.

```
  function getData(id, explored) {
    var self = this;
    let explored = visited && visited.length>0 ?  visited : new Array();
        fetch("https://test.com/id", function(data){
             //here im checking if its the end child:
             if (data.end) {
               var end =[];
                end.push(data.end); // o/p: endId: "7287382"
              }else {
              let s = new Array();
               data.forEach(function(n){
                  s.push(n);
               })
              var t = s.shift();
              explored.push(t);
              self.getData(t,explored)
            }
        });
    }
```

any ideas?

Comment: DFS is frequently written recursively, which makes it easy to backtrack as the recursion unwinds. If you're hoping for a concrete answer, It would be helpful if you showed what `data` looked like.

Comment: You would need a stack of explored nodes (each with their children), not a queue. Then you'd go exploring the first child or the node on the top of the stack, and pop nodes when they have no children any more. However, a much easier implementation would be to use a recursive solution with `async`/`await`.

Comment: What should happen to the results, do you want to put them in a structure? Currently you're not doing anything with the `end`.

Comment: @Bergi, for ```end``` just want to print them, collecting them in an array and will display after the entire tree is traversed

Comment: @Bergi: can you help me or direct how to use the ```async``` and ```await``  for this ex?

Comment: @user1234 Do you know how promises work?